# Group CSS Classes in One

Tags: css

I already tried combining two CSS classes in one but I could not. Does anyone know how to do it?

.fontsize { font-size: small; }
.color1 { color: red;}
.color2 {color: blue;}
.textred { **combine .fontsize + .color1** }
.textblue { **combine .fontsize + .color2** }

```
<div class="textblue">example</div>
<div class="textred">example red</div>
```

I did not want to use:

```
<div class="fontsize color1">example</div>
```

Comment: You might want to look into [scss/sass](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html), which even then might not be perfect for your needs.

Comment: What is the reason for not wanting to  use dual classes?

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ Two classes was just an example, in fact I need to use 6 classes :) kkkkkkkkk Each page has about 50 items, each with 6 classes.
<div class = "one two three four five six">
<div class = "one two three eight seven nine">
<div class = "one three four five nine ten">

So I wanted to do this:

<div class = "group1">
<div class = "group2">
<div class = "group3"> .... Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that? You may try this:

```
.fontsize, .textblue, .textred{ font-size: small; }
.color1 { color: red;}
.color2{color: blue;}
```

As AbsoluteƵERØ said in the comments, dual classes are perfectly fine. There is no reason that I can think of to not use dual classes in this case.

Comment: See my answer above AbsoluteƵERØ to understand my reasons... Thank you for your help!

Comment: Wow... that's a lot of classes!

Comment: Yes... And I don't have other way, i need to use all of them.

Comment: Then, as far as I know, my answer is the only way you can do this. Of course, there is another solution using JavaScript. Just one thing. Say you have two conflicting classes. Which class gets priority?